# LISTAGG in vertica

Tags: vertica, listagg

Equivalent of LISTAGG in Vertica
Hello Everyone!
I'm trying to aggregate all the field values of a particular group in one field.
For example, My input table looks like :-

```
FIELD1 GROUP1

A 1

A 2

B 1

B 2

C 1

C 3

3 null
```

and my output should look like :-

```
1 A,B,C

2 A,B

3 C
```

I can currently achieve this on Oracle by using the following function

```
SELECT GROUP1, LISTAGG(FIELD1, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FIELD1) AS GROUPED_FIELD
FROM <INPUT_TABLE>
GROUP BY GROUP1;
```

Is there a way i can do this in Vertica.
Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertica just added support for LISTAGG in the latest 9.1.1: https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Aggregate/LISTAGG.htm

However, it does not support ORDER BY clause, but you can use this workaround:

```
select listagg(col1), col2
from (
  select col1, col2 from table1 order by col2, col1
) x
group by col2
```

Answer (score 2):

you have no built-in function but you can use UDX
see [vertica github](https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Extension-Packages/tree/master/strings_package) you need GroupConcat function

Comment: Thanks for your response . I have tried to  create a UDF with below command.
CREATE LIBRARY AggregateFunctionsConcatenate AS '/opt/vertica/sdk/examples/AggregateFunctions/Concatenate.so';
CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION agg_group_concat AS LANGUAGE 'C++' NAME 'ConcatenateFactory'LIBRARY AggregateFunctionsConcatenate;
but getting below Error :
[Code: 4746, SQL State: 42V13]  [Vertica][VJDBC](4746) ROLLBACK: Setting up function "ConcatenateFactory" failed
 undefined symbol: getConcatenateFactory

Comment: currently getting : [Code: 4746, SQL State: 42V13]  [Vertica][VJDBC](4746) ROLLBACK: Setting up function "agg_group_concat" failed
  [Vertica][VJDBC]Detail: [Incompatible factory type]

Comment: can you share the source code for Concatenate.so‌​ ?

Comment: hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/45921202/2655092, it seems your returnType in factory is wrong, share your code

Comment: @IgorB checkout my implementation too ;)

Comment: Thanks , yeah my factory name in source code was diffrent.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on my implementation of [LISTAGG](https://github.com/sKwa/vertica/blob/master/UDx/ListAgg.cpp), it actually mimics an Oracle function `LISTAGG`. `GROUP_CONCAT` and `CONCATENATE`in git hub have some disadvantaged.

**Compile:**

```
g++ -D HAVE_LONG_INT_64  -I /opt/vertica/sdk/include \
    -Wall -shared -Wno-unused-value -fPIC            \
    -o ListAggLib.so ListAgg.cpp /opt/vertica/sdk/include/Vertica.cpp
```

**Install:**

```
CREATE LIBRARY ListAggLib AS '/home/dbadmin/ListAggLib.so';
CREATE ANALYTIC FUNCTION ListAgg AS LANGUAGE 'C++' NAME 'ListAggFactory' LIBRARY ListAggLib;
```

**Example:**

```
dbadmin=> select * from foo;
 id |    date    | val 
----+------------+-----
  1 | 2000-01-01 | rus
  1 | 2000-01-01 | usa
  1 | 2000-01-02 | usa
  1 | 2000-01-03 | eng
  2 | 2000-01-01 | afg
  2 | 2000-01-02 | eng
(6 rows)

dbadmin=> select distinct id, ListAgg(val) over(partition by id) from foo;
 id |    ?column?     
----+-----------------
  1 | rus,usa,usa,eng
  2 | afg,eng
(2 rows)

dbadmin=> select id, val,
dbadmin-> ListAgg(val) over(partition by id) from foo group by id, val order by id;
 id | val |  ?column?   
----+-----+-------------
  1 | eng | eng,rus,usa
  1 | rus | eng,rus,usa
  1 | usa | eng,rus,usa
  2 | afg | afg,eng
  2 | eng | afg,eng
(5 rows)

dbadmin=> select 
dbadmin->     id,
dbadmin->     val,
dbadmin->     ListAgg(val using parameters delimiter=';') over(partition by id) 
dbadmin-> from foo 
dbadmin-> group by id, val 
dbadmin-> order by id;
 id | val |  ?column?   
----+-----+-------------
  1 | eng | eng;rus;usa
  1 | rus | eng;rus;usa
  1 | usa | eng;rus;usa
  2 | afg | afg;eng
  2 | eng | afg;eng
(5 rows)
```

Comment: It looks like a Transform function... not an Aggregate.

Comment: @mauro so check it by your self, its an analytical function ;)

Comment: @mauro exactly, that was a error , after changing it to Transform function everything worked