# Vertica LISTAGG not defined

Tags: sql, vertica, listagg

As far as I can tell from the [Vertica 8.1.x docs](https://www.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Aggregate/LISTAGG.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Functions%7CAggregate%2520Functions%7C_____20) LISTAGG is supported for versions of Vertica 8.1.x and up; however, when I try to use this function I am seeing the following:

> SQL Error [3457] [42883]: [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Function
>   LISTAGG(varchar) does not exist, or permission is denied for
>   LISTAGG(varchar)

While executing:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(myColumn) FROM myTable;
```

I saw in another Stack Overflow post that LISTAGG was introduced in v9.1 [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951892/listagg-in-vertica). I am currently using version v9.0.1-19

**Can anyone confirm or provide insight as to why LISTAGG might not be working?**

Comment: Listagg should be in version 9.0:  https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Aggregate/LISTAGG.htm.

Comment: `SELECT LISTAGG (myColumn) FROM myTable;`

Comment: I am getting this error in version v9.3.1-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm it was added in version v9.1.1-4. See it in the [v9.1.4 new features page](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/NewFeatures/9.1/9.1.1/SQLandFunctions.htm%3FTocPath%3DVertica%25209.1.x%2520New%2520Features%2520and%2520Changes%7CVertica%25209.1.1%7C_____11)

I have 2 Vertica DBs, 1st with v9.0.1-5 and 2nd with v9.2.0-7. `LISTAGG()` is available on the 2nd but not on the 1st:

```
dbadmin=> select version();
              version               
------------------------------------
 Vertica Analytic Database v9.0.1-5

dbadmin=> SELECT LISTAGG(myColumn) FROM myTable;
ERROR 3457:  Function LISTAGG(varchar) does not exist, or permission is denied for LISTAGG(varchar)
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts
```

```
              version               
------------------------------------
 Vertica Analytic Database v9.2.0-7

dbadmin=> SELECT LISTAGG(myColumn) FROM myTable;
 LISTAGG 
---------
 aaa,abc
```

`LISTAGG()` is part of `/opt/vertica/packages/VFunctions` package, and it's the only function in the `v_func` schema in v9.1.1 and above.

---

A good alternative is `GROUP_CONCAT()` which is part of [string_packages](https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Extension-Packages/tree/master/strings_package) UDx. See the readme for installation instructions and usage.