# How avoid - User defined aggregate cannot be used in query with other distinct aggregates

Tags: sql, vertica

I have error

> [0A000][5366] [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: User defined aggregate cannot be used in query with other distinct aggregates

when I execute

```
SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT a USING PARAMETERS separator=',', max_length = 10) AS a,
       COUNT(DISTINCT b)                                                   AS b
FROM t
```

Do I have a way to avoid this aggregation and have the same logic?

In real project I have a complex query with many "subselect" and "with as", "group by" logic, so I wonder how it is possible to refactor, how many way I have?

I read the links, but no ideas how combine COUNT DISTINCT and LISTAGG DISTINCT: https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Aggregate/COUNTAggregate.htm
https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Aggregate/LISTAGG.htm

DB: Vertica Analytic Database v10.1.1-3

UDP: solution with the help of @Kendle

```
(WITH zz as (SELECT a, b FROM mkt_dwh.t) -- "where", "group by" logic
 SELECT a, b
 FROM (WITH aa AS (SELECT DISTINCT a FROM zz),
            bb AS (SELECT COUNT(b) as b FROM zz)
       SELECT LISTAGG(distinct aa.a USING PARAMETERS separator=',', max_length = 1000) AS a,
              bb.b                                                                     AS b
       FROM aa,
            bb
       GROUP BY bb.b) as test);
```

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    a VARCHAR,
    b VARCHAR
);


INSERT INTO mkt_dwh.t
VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO mkt_dwh.t
VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO mkt_dwh.t
VALUES ('2', '2');
INSERT INTO mkt_dwh.t
VALUES ('2', '3');
INSERT INTO mkt_dwh.t
VALUES ('3', '3');

SELECT LISTAGG(a USING PARAMETERS separator=',', max_length = 1000) AS a,
       COUNT(distinct b)                                            AS b
FROM mkt_dwh.t;
select count(*)
FROM mkt_dwh.t;

SELECT LISTAGG(distinct aa.a USING PARAMETERS separator=',', max_length = 1000) AS a,
       COUNT(bb.b)                                                              AS b
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a FROM mkt_dwh.t) aa,
     (SELECT DISTINCT b FROM mkt_dwh.t) bb;

(WITH zz as (SELECT a, b FROM mkt_dwh.t) -- some where, group by logic
 SELECT a, b
 FROM (WITH aa AS (SELECT DISTINCT a FROM zz),
            bb AS (SELECT COUNT(b) as b FROM zz)
       SELECT LISTAGG(distinct aa.a USING PARAMETERS separator=',', max_length = 1000) AS a,
              bb.b                                                                     AS b
       FROM aa,
            bb
       GROUP BY bb.b) as test);
```

Comment: What version are you using? It seems that `listagg()` was added in version 9; See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56841313/vertica-listagg-not-defined

Comment: @Kendle Vertica Analytic Database v10.1.1-3

In the link, I see not related error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sub-queries to do the distinct.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(aa.a USING PARAMETERS separator=',', max_length = 10) AS a,
       COUNT(bb.b)                                                   AS b
FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT a FROM t) aa,
  (SELECT DISTINCT b FROM t) bb;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a possible solution, isn't there a more straightforward solution?

 WITH aa AS (SELECT DISTINCT a FROM t),
     bb AS (SELECT COUNT(b) as b FROM t)
SELECT LISTAGG(distinct aa.a USING PARAMETERS separator=',', max_length = 1000) AS a,
       bb.b                                                                     AS b
FROM aa,
     bb
GROUP BY bb.b;

Comment: You can write it as CTE `with x as (select) ` or as sub-queries. I don't know that there is any difference for the performance. A CTE is clearer when it is long but here the sub-queries are so short that a CTE seems heavy.