Vertica Mutliple Listagg statements
Is it possible to have mutliple listagg statements in a query. I know in oracle I can have multiple listagg columns. I am getting an error when attempting to build a single table with the columns.
The WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) doesnt work either in Vertica
    SELECT ID,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT serv_yr) AS SRV_YR,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT serv_yrmo) AS SRV_YRMO
    FROM table_x x 
    GROUP BY 1

SQL Error [5366] [0A000]: [Vertica][VJDBC](5366) 
ERROR: User defined aggregate cannot be used in query with other distinct aggregates


can you provide a few dozen rows - even just with serv_yr , serv_yrmo and id from table_x, so I can play with it?

This might helpful for you @Tinkinc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71485327/how-avoid-user-defined-aggregate-cannot-be-used-in-query-with-other-distinct-a

It seems as though the vertica version I am using doesnt allow WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) which allows for multiple listaggs.

The error message - at least in Version 23.x - is, in fact:
ERROR 10752:  User defined distinct aggregate cannot be used in query with other distinct aggregates.
It's the two DISTINCT expression in one select list that causes the issue, here: you can only group by one set of grouping columns in the same query - and each DISTINCT expression is translated into its own set of grouping columns.
This is the third solution I found to the problem: avoid DISTINCT by using Vertica's collection type that does not allow duplicate entries: the SET. My favourite, actually.
I kept solution two and one at the bottom of this.
Only that it returns a SET literal rather than a string in CSV format. But you could even change it further to CSV format, by applying a TO_JSON() function to the resulting SET - and optionally removing the square brackets of the JSON notation.
WITH
-- some input ...
table_x(id,serv_yr,serv_yrmo) AS (
            SELECT  1, 2022, 202201
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2022, 202204
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2022, 202207
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2022, 202207
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2022, 202210
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2023, 202301
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2023, 202304
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2023, 202307
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2023, 202307
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2023, 202310
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2022, 202201
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2022, 202204
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2022, 202207
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2022, 202207
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2022, 202210
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2023, 202301
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2023, 202304
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2023, 202307
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2023, 202307
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2023, 202310
)
SELECT
  id
, IMPLODE(serv_yr)  ::SET[INT] AS srv_yr
, IMPLODE(serv_yrmo)::SET[INT] AS srv_yrmo
FROM table_x
GROUP BY 1;

This is the second solution I found to the problem - and I find it better. I kept the old one at the bottom of this.
Get one of the two DISTINCT-s out of the way in one subquery, and apply the second DISTINCT in the LISTAGG expression in the outermost query, which selects from the mentioned subquery:
-- some input ...
table_x(id,serv_yr,serv_yrmo) AS (
            SELECT  1, 2022, 202201
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2022, 202204
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2022, 202207
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2022, 202207
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2022, 202210
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2023, 202301
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2023, 202304
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2023, 202307
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2023, 202307
  UNION ALL SELECT  1, 2023, 202310
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2022, 202201
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2022, 202204
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2022, 202207
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2022, 202207
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2022, 202210
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2023, 202301
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2023, 202304
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2023, 202307
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2023, 202307
  UNION ALL SELECT  2, 2023, 202310
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
dedupe_ym AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    id
  , serv_yr
  , serv_yrmo 
  FROM table_x
)
SELECT 
  id
, LISTAGG(DISTINCT serv_yr) AS srv_yr
, LISTAGG(serv_yrmo)        AS srv_yrmo
FROM dedupe_ym
GROUP BY 1;

The old solution is also - divide and conquer:

get the first LISTAGG() in one subquery
join the output of that subquery back to the base table, and group again, this time by the id and the LISTAGG() output obtained in the subquery:

WITH
yr_agg(id,srv_yr) AS (
  SELECT                 
    id
  , LISTAGG(DISTINCT serv_yr)   AS srv_yr
  FROM table_x
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT
  table_x.id
, srv_yr
, LISTAGG(DISTINCT serv_yrmo) AS srv_yrmo
FROM table_x
JOIN yr_agg USING(id)
GROUP BY 1,2;


Thanks. We can agree in Oracle 11g + this is not the case when adding the WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) ?

True. But, we also can simplify the Vertica query by working with the SET complex type. I'll modify my answer accordingly
