# How to Group By a column without adding another column with aggregate function

Tags: sql, vertica

I am trying to get a group by for a column "Order_contract_Number" with type as an another column where i am using "Count" aggregator in "case when" function based on "product class" which is another column from the source.
Now the issue is that the product class is multiple for same "Order_contract_Number" and the issue araises when i NEED to use "Product class" also in the group by which is causing the issue.
Below is the code of what i have written.

```
SELECT "ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBER",
   CASE
      WHEN COUNT(distinct "product_class_Sheet1"."PRODUCT CLASS")>1
      THEN 'MIXED TYPE : '||."PRODUCT CLASS" 
      WHEN COUNT(distinct "product_class_Sheet1"."PRODUCT CLASS")=1
      THEN "product_class_Sheet1"."PRODUCT CLASS"||' ONLY '
      ELSE NULL END AS TYPE
  FROM 
  "product_class_Sheet1"
  GROUP BY
    "product_class_Sheet1"."ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBER"
  , "product_class_Sheet1"."PRODUCT CLASS"
```

I want the outcome to be

```
|      ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBER      |     TYPE             |
|---------------------------------|----------------------|
|          1                      |         MIXED TYPE A |
|          1                      |         MIXED TYPE B | 
|          2                      |         A Only       |
|          3                      |         MIXED TYPE A |
|          3                      |         MIXED TYPE B |
|          3                      |         MIXED TYPE C |
|          3                      |         MIXED TYPE D |
|          3                      |         MIXED TYPE E |
```

But what i am getting is

```
|      ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBER      |     TYPE             |
|---------------------------------|----------------------|
|          1                      |         A ONLY       |
|          1                      |         B ONLY       |
|          2                      |         A ONLY       |
|          3                      |         A ONLY       |
|          3                      |         B ONLY       |
|          3                      |         C ONLY       | 
|          3                      |         D ONLY       |
|          3                      |         E ONLY       |
```

The Source is :

```
|      ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBER      |     PRODUCT CLASS    |
|---------------------------------|----------------------|
|          1                      |         A            |
|          1                      |         B            |
|          2                      |         A            |
|          3                      |         A            |
|          3                      |         B            |
|          3                      |         C            |
|          3                      |         D            |
|          3                      |         E            |
```

Please let me know how i can tackle this.
Thank you

Comment: Hi - please don't use images, use editable text instead so that people can copy your data if they want to try out a solution. Also, your source data has a column called "Product Type" but your code is referring to "Product Class"

Comment: Hi @NickW I have made the changes as you suugested.

Comment: is there any more data in the source table?

Comment: Yes There are other ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBERS which are similar to this.
this is just an example

Comment: are there any combinations of ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBER and PRODUCT_CLASS which are not unique in the source-table? Else this seems fine to me... the count will always be 1 for unique combinations, and thus the second part of the when statement will be followed...

Comment: @Bert-JanStroop I want it to follow the first case when and come out as mixed.
How should i change my statement for it?

Comment: Show some additional tuples/rows in the source table so we'd understand what you're asking

Comment: @D.Rattansingh I have added more examples in source as well as the expected outcome

Comment: You're grouping by a couple variables, also containing "PRODUCT CLASS". That means that within each group there is only 1 "PRODUCT CLASS". If  you then count distinct "PRODUCT CLASS" the amount will always be 1, and thus the first part of the when statement will never be reached.

Comment: @Bert-JanStroop Tried with removing the distinct too. It is still counting the individual product class and one without grouping the order_contract_numbers there by going with the second case when

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    A."ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBER", 
    case 
        when count > 1 then 'MIXED TYPE : '||"PRODUCT CLASS" 
        when count = 1 then "PRODUCT CLASS"||' ONLY ' 
        else NULL 
    end as Type 
from source A 
left join 
    (SELECT 
        "ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBER", 
        count(*) 
     FROM source 
     group by "ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBER") B 
on 
    A."ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBER" = B."ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBER"
```

[image]

> Comment: Thank you . This worked perfectly. Can you also show how more
> than one type for the same order number can be put into the same line,
> like a concatenation? –  Rahul Bhat  1 hour ago

```
SELECT 
    "ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBER", 
    case when count(*) > 1 then 'MIXED TYPE : '||LISTAGG(distinct "PRODUCT CLASS")
    else max("PRODUCT CLASS")||' ONLY ' end as type
 FROM source 
 group by "ORDER_CONTRACT_NUMBER"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you . This worked perfectly. Can you also show how more than one type for the same order number can be put into the same line, like a concatenation?

Comment: You mean like "MIXED TYPE: A/B" for the order_Contracct_number 1?

Comment: Yes please. Sorry for not including it in the original description

Comment: Added it to the sollution

Comment: Thank you . Unfortunately that is not being supported in the db im using . Il check out for any other functions similar.

Comment: Adjusted it in code. Somehow got confused you were using Postgresql. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle**:

```
select order_contract_number, 
    CASE
        WHEN count(*)>1 THEN 'MIXED TYPE : '|| listagg(productclass, ', ')
        WHEN count(*)=1 THEN listagg(productclass, ', ') ||' ONLY '
    ELSE NULL END AS TYPE
from source
group by order_contract_number;
```

**source**:

[image]

**output**:

[image]

Comment: I am getting an "Execution error: ERROR: Column "product_class_Sheet1.PRODUCT CLASS" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" and when i use "PRODUCT CLASS" in the group by, im getting the old result again

Comment: ok, makes sense. you may need a subquery for this. give me some time

Comment: @RahulBhat let me know if this works. I tested it in oracle

Comment: Unfortunately this isnt working in vertica. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @RahulBhat what is the error? If it's the listagg function, see this post for an equivalent in vertica : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951892/listagg-in-vertica

Answer (score 0):

Pivot the input into dedicated columns in a GROUP BY query, then join the base input with that pivot, check if both pivoted values are NOT NULL to decide whether you use 'MIXED' or 'ONLY' .

I added two additional rows to your input to demonstrate the behaviour in all three possible cases.

It would also work if you had several equal combinations of order_contract_number and product_class.

```
WITH 
-- your input ...
indata(order_contract_number,product_class) AS (
          SELECT 1,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'B'
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
analysed AS (
  SELECT
    order_contract_number
  , MAX(CASE product_class WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END) AS a_count
  , MAX(CASE product_class WHEN 'B' THEN 1 END) AS b_count
  FROM indata
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT
  i.order_contract_number
, CASE
    WHEN a.a_count IS NOT NULL AND a.b_count IS NOT NULL
    THEN 'MIXED TYPE '
    ELSE 'ONLY  TYPE '
  END ||product_class AS type
FROM indata   AS i
JOIN analysed AS a USING(order_contract_number)
 order_contract_number |     type     
-----------------------+--------------
                     1 | MIXED TYPE A
                     1 | MIXED TYPE B
                     2 | ONLY  TYPE A
                     3 | ONLY  TYPE B
```

Comment: The above input and output which i have added in the description is an example. There are more than 200K rows in that product_class file.
Can you please provide a change in that clause of your "indata"

Comment: In which clause? How many product_class -es do you have? The example works for only type 'A' and 'B'. Otherwise, we'll have to do it differently, using a SELECT DISTINCT and looking for COUNT(*) > 1 from outside. You should at best add at least about 12 exemplary rows.

Comment: the WITH clause which you have added at the top manually adding the "select 1,A UNION ALL..." there are only 6 PRODUCT CLASS types but 200K distinct order_contract_numbers